# Cabal and zlib on OS X

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

When I run "cabal update" on my Mac (Snow Leopard, Intel), I get:

% cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
cabal: Codec.Compression.Zlib: incompatible zlib version

Anyone else seeing this?  Reinstalling the Haskell Platform hasn't helped.  I'm unable to install or update Cabal packages at the moment, so I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the latest Haskell Platform from the binary installer?

Comment: Yep, I downloaded it two days ago, ran the uninstall script and then ran the installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed this by removing MacPorts completely from my machine, re-installing zlib with it, and then clearing out my ~/.cabal.

After that I stopped getting these messages.

Thanks, all.

Answer (score 1):

> Incompatible zlib version

I  think this means the C zlib library you have installed is out of date. Can you update it?

Comment: I just installed the latest zlib and reinstalled the Haskell Platform.  Same thing...

Comment: Can you confirm what version of zlib the scripts are trying to link haskell-zlib against?

Comment: So, if I rename ~/.cabal to make it inaccessible, "cabal update" works without a hitch.

Comment: Removing ~/.cabal/lib/zlib-0.5.2.0 did the trick!

cabal is now happily updating.

Thanks for the help - hopefully this post will help if someone encounters the same issue.

Comment: I spoke too soon...I was asked to update cabal-install and after doing so I get the same error again.

Comment: Sounds like you had a binary that was built against one version of zlib, but downloaded and built cabal-install again against a different one. Look carefully at the C zlib installations on your system.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is install zlib from MacPorts with the +universal flag and that works without problems. Does this help you?